# How to deny access to subfolder in svn for specific member

Tags: svn

I am using subversion v1.6.11 in CentOS.
Using Apache httpd to interface with Web browser.

I have created several folders in svn.
I have few subfolders in one of the svn repository.
I have added 2 members to an svn repository.
I want to selectively allow those two access to 3 subfolders in the svn project.

John user is one among the two users present in the svn repository.
I have tried to set john = for subfolder A to block John from accessing the sbfolder.
But that doesn't cause any differenc

Answer (score 0):

Read [Path-Based Authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) chapter  and [Per-directory access control](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.perdir) in SVN Book

For Apache you have to:

- Load authz_svn_module module
- Add `AuthzSVNAccessFile /path/to/access/file` to SVN location in httpd.conf
- Write access-rules to access-file according to 1-st URL